# Copying Large Files to Build Directory?

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to copy all files in a directory to a specified output directory in such a way that they are only copied when they are changed or when a new file is added to the directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`file`**](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html#file) command to copy all the files in given directory to another path, e.g. to build directory. This operation will happen during CMake.

```
file(GLOB files_to_copy
    -your-data-dir-/*.*
)
file(COPY ${files_to_copy} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

Comment: `This operation will happen during CMake.` I need it to happen so that it is a dependency of building an executable. So when i build an executable and a file was added to the directory, it'll copy the file over.